# Two build agents one release pipeline - need to limit

Tags: azure-devops

I have two build agents running on the same machine. The reason for two agents, is we have sufficient builds requests to need more than one, especially when a release is occurring which can be well over 10 minutes taking up a build agent.

Two build agents works well for the build process when we are running different build definitions. But trying to run two of the same build definition or especially a release definition causes all sorts of parallel issues.

How do I prevent the same build or release definition from being execute at the same time on different build agents ?

EDIT : The only solution that I can come up with is, have two pools. One build and one release and therefore they will never get a chance to run twice on the same definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add capabilities to your build agents, then specify demands to your build definition or release definition, after that the builds and releases will run in the corresponding agents that its demands are existing in agents’ capabilities.

Agent:

[image]

Build definition:
[image]

Release Definition:

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I can use this to limit one of my agents to be release only.